# Scala: Expression, Value, Type

Tags: scala

I am going through a Scala book, and it states few concepts like:

```
Expression evaluates to a value
A value a an object
Expression has a type
A value doesn't have a type
```

Value is an object but it doesn't have a type.

How is it possible? In jvm, objects are of certain type, isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction here is that objects have a *class*, but it's not the same as a type. E.g.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
```

The *type* of `list` is `List[Int]`; when you run the program, you can see in the debugger (or by calling `list.getClass`) that its class is something called `$colon$colon` (which corresponds to `::` in Scala code).

```
 val list2 = List.empty[Int]
 val list3 = List("")
```

`list2` has the same type as `list1`, but a different class; `list3` has a different type, but the same class.